# What is the proper way of loading of classes using namespace. So that i don't have to include autoload in every file?

Tags: php, oop

Hello i have a task to do to class the classes by its namespace. My requirement is to load the classes without including the require keyword for autoload.php.

```
<?php
namespace classes;
class test {
public function getPrint(){
    echo "Hello";
}
}
```

This is the class with namespace. Here is the code for to class functions.

```
require_once 'classes/autoload.php';
use classes\test2;

$dt = new test();
$dt2 = new test2();


$dt->getPrint();
echo $dt2->Okay();
```

I am autoloading the classes. my problem is to load the classes with using

```
require_once 'classes/autoload.php';
```

This line. I have to use this line in every code file to load the classes. What is the proper way to load the classes. So i do not have to include

```
require_once 'classes/autoload.php';
```

this in every file?

Comment: You will have to `require` *something somewhere*. The usual way frameworks are solving this is to have one *bootstrap* file, i.e. something that every single request gets routed through that includes all necessary (autoload-)files and sets up configurations before continuing to handle the details of the request.

Comment: Can you show me an example? @deceze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way this works is to use one bootstrap file that each request goes through. This also usually requires to move *routing* into the PHP code; i.e. instead of `example.com/foo/bar.php` simply invoking the file `foo/bar.php`, you'd usually use [*pretty URLs*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476) like `example.com/foo/bar`, and then figure out in your PHP code what `foo/bar` means exactly and what it should do (though this is pretty optional and up to you to decide).

First you set up an `.htacess` file like this, or add an equivalent configuration in your web server config files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ bootstrap.php
```

This causes your web server to invoke `bootstrap.php` for any and all requests whose file doesn't actually exist (i.e. `css/style.css` would still be served as is, but `foo/bar` is not an actual file and would invoke `bootstrap.php` instead).

In `bootstrap.php` you'd then `require` all the necessary files like auto-loaders and perhaps configuration files, and then run whatever class, function or file you want:

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/autoload.php';

$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
require "$request.php";
```

The above is a simple example for taking the requested URI (e.g. `/foo/bar`) and using it to `require` a PHP file. **This is very naïve and potentially dangerous**, so you'll want to do some more custom processing in actual use.

Comment: Thank you this helps me. This can be done using MVC.

Comment: MVC is typically paired with this, yes, but is ultimately a separate concept and technique (though something you'll typically want to do, yes).

Answer (score -1):

You could create a file which requires all other files you want to use, including the autoload:

```
<?php

require_once('classes/autoload.php');
require_once('file1.php');
require_once('file2.php');
...
```

Then you won't need to require the autoload, as files are already appended after it.

Comment: Your answer tells me that there is no way without require? We must have to include files to autoload the classes?

Comment: I don't know your project structure. Each script which will access the classes from autoload must include one way or another the autoload file. Including all scripts in a single file with autoload on top of it makes more sense and resolves this problem. However it will solve the issue depending on your project structure.

Comment: my structure is procedural php code and i ahve to convert that code into OOP with routing includes. So, i think i have to convert it into MVC that will help me put all the scripts in same page.

Comment: You should go for a framework such as Codeigniter or Laravel if you want to rebuild it in MVC patter. They could help you.